# Edit CSS Using Razor/Sitecore

Tags: html, css, razor, sitecore, sitecore7

We have a component that contains a background image. Our front-end guy needs it to be loaded through CSS (i.e. `background: url(/*path here*/)...`). The following is a possible solution we came up with:

```
@string src = // Get image path from Sitecore().Field("Picture");

<div style="background: url(@src) left top no-repeat;"> ... </div>
```

However, there are two problems with this approach:

1. It makes it very difficult for the content editor to swap out the image. They will have to manually change it through `edit item`.
2. It feels like a hack/workaround.

So the question is as follows: **Is there a way to edit the CSS of an element through Razor/Sitecore? Specifically, the `background:` field.**

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case and I used :

```
<footer class="layout_footer" style="background-color: @Model.BackgroundColor">
 on view rendering (cshtml file)
```

And on the model we have :

```
    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField =((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)item.Fields["BackgroundImage"]);

            return Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem);                   
        }
    }
```

For editing this field in page editor you can use Sitecore Field Editor from a command : http://blog.istern.dk/2012/05/21/running-sitecore-field-editor-from-a-command/

Comment: That is definitely much cleaner than the current approach and makes sense. However, it does seem like a lot of extra work to implement MVC on what was once a simple `View Rendering`. I'll check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check for edit mode, and display in edit mode a editable field. Also create a Custom Experience Button from the Field Editor Button Type. You can also display. See [User friendly developing with the Sitecore Experience Editor](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/the-experience-editor/)

```
@string src = // Get image path from Sitecore().Field("Picture");

<div style="background: url(@src) left top no-repeat;"> 
    @if (IsInEditingMode)
    {
        <h3>Backgroiund Picture: @Editable(m => m.Picture)</h3>
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Sitecore extension method which will do this out of the box (i.e. `@Html.Sitecore().Field("fieldName")` will not work here as it would render the entire image tag (also a load of other non-image markup in page editor mode) as you probably know.

The method that @sitecore climber mentions is useful for controller renderings (or view renderings with a custom RenderingModel). If you want to stick with simple view renderings (i.e. not create a RenderingModel) then you could create a Html extension method which can be re-used on any view rendering. This could be something like the following:

```
public string ImageFieldSrc(this SitecoreHelper sitecoreHelper, string fieldName, Item item = null)
{
    if (item == null) {
       item = sitecoreHelper.CurrentItem;
    }
    var imageField = new ImageField(item.Fields[fieldName]);
    var mediaItem = imageField.MediaItem;
    var mediaUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
    mediaUrl = HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(mediaUrl); //if you want to use media request protection (adding the hash onto the end of the URL, use this line
    return mediaUrl; 
}
```

It's worth noting that if you are using Sitecore 7.5 or above there is a feature to protect media URLs with a hash to prevent malicious DoS type attacks [described in this blog post by Adam Najmanowicz](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2015/05/15/do-not-turn-sitecore-media-request-protection-off-and-protect-older-sitecore-versions-with-imageguard/).

In summary; if you are using Sitecore 7.5+ and you use media hashing then you will need to call `HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl` on the media URL if it is to respect size parameters.